# How to change Stripe's API version for testing, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

We're managing an old Rails app that uses Stripe but our Stripe version 26 months behind the current API. We're looking to upgrade to the current Stripe API but because many changes will affect our system, we'd really like a way to test out the changes before we change the live API that our live site is using.

So I have two questions:

1) When working with the API we rely heavily on the distinction between Live and Test modes. Is there any way to upgrade the Test mode API only (without upgrading Live) so we can identify and correct for any breakage without actually breaking the user experience?

2) Is it possible to upgrade the API one version at a time, rather than all-at-once, to make the transition more manageable for us?

Answer (score 22):

It's extremely poorly documented, but it turns out you can change the Stripe API version to any version you want on a per-request basis by setting `Stripe.api_version = 'YYYY-MM-DD'` before sending a request using the Ruby bindings (https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#versioning), or by sending a `Stripe-Version` HTTP header.

So we'll plan to configure our specs to use the latest API version for all requests, and test for breakage that way.

Comment: But this does not apply to webhook calls which are originated from Stripe servers, right?

Comment: Good question, I don't remember. I think you can also set the API version in the online Stripe settings; maybe that determines the behavior of webhooks.

Comment: This worked for me, but I am using the VCR gem and ended up needing to delete all the cassettes before the changed version could be seen in the header.

Comment: This is an area where the Stripe API is lacking, in my opinion. API calls can me made in any version but events in the dashboard always use the default version. Webhooks can be set to either default or latest API version, nothing in between.

Comment: For webhooks - the way we upgraded was to delete all our test endpoints and create new ones that was set to use the latest api version. Then we verified that everything was working in the test environment before upgrading the account version.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one-way to override the Stripe version at a fine-grained level within your code.

This works by overriding the `Stripe.api_version` accessor method to look for a version in a thread local variable, or if it doesn't find one, falls back to the original behaviour. `Stripe.api_version` is used as the value of the `Stripe-Version` HTTP header in [`lib/stripe.rb`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/v1.58.0/lib/stripe.rb#L425).

**Note** this is for stripe gem version 1.58.0 and has not been tested with other versions:

First, create the file `config/initializers/stripe_api_version_overrider.rb` with contents:

```
module StripeAPIVersionOverrider
  def api_version
    Thread.current[:__stripe_api_version_override] || super
  end

  def with_api_version(version, &block)
    original_version = api_version
    Thread.current[:__stripe_api_version_override] = version
    block.call
  ensure
    Thread.current[:__stripe_api_version_override] = original_version
  end
end

Stripe.singleton_class.prepend(StripeAPIVersionOverrider)
```

Next, in your code where you want to use a different version of the Stripe API, wrap it in a block passed to `Stripe.with_api_version`:

```
Stripe.with_api_version "2016-07-06" do
  # API versions prior to 2016-07-06 did not support
  # retrieving canceled subscriptions.
  Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(subscription_id)
end
```

Run `bin/spring stop` to ensure these changes will be loaded into your development environment.